# Python 3.5.1: I have three versions on my Mac, how to tidy up?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

On my Mac, it looks like I've ended up with 3 versions of python 3.5.1. The most practical issue is that I don't know how to make sure libraries are available to all of them. For instance, in jupyter I get `ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'`

If in jupyter I do `sys.path` I get:

```
['',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/ada/.ipython']
```

if in the terminal I run `python3` and then do the same, I get:

```
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

if I do it in spyder, my python IDE, I get:

```
['',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python35.zip',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.5',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.5/site-packages.zip',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/ada/.ipython']
```

Suggestions for cleaning this up? Yes, I've done a lot of googling, every time I try something I end up with an additional version!

Comment: i dont recommend remove any of them.  alternatively, you can install `virtualenv` and create a virtual environment for your preferred python version